# Typo in Lang's *Algebra*, Proposition X.2.5.: if $a_M$ is not locally nilpotent, there exists $x \in M$ such that $a^n x = 0$ for all $n \geq 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules, maximal-and-prime-ideals, nilpotence

While reading through Chapter X of Lang's *Algebra*, I came across following definitions and results. In my opinion, something seems wrong in the proof of Proposition 2.5. (page 418, third edition).

Some prior results:

> **Proposition 2.1.** Let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $A$, and assume that $S$ does not contain $0$. Then there exists an ideal of $A$ which is maximal in the set of ideals not intersecting $S$, and any such ideal is prime.
>
> **Lemma 2.4.** Let $x$ be an element of an $A$-module $M$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $A$. Then $(Ax)_\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$ if and only if $\mathfrak{p}$ contains the annihilator of $x$.

Let $a \in A$ and $M$ be an $A$-module. We denote by $a_M$ the homomorphisms $x \mapsto ax$, $x \in M$. We shall now say that $a_M$ is *locally nilpotent* if for each $x \in M$ there exists an integer $n(x)\geq 1$ such that $a^{n(x)}x=0$.

Now, the statement and proof of Proposition 2.5.:

> **Proposition 2.5.** Let $M$ be a module, $a \in A$. Then $a_M$ is locally nilpotent if and only if $a$ lies in every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $M_\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$.

*Proof.* The first part of the proof shows that when $a_M$ is locally nilpotent, $a$ lies in every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $M_\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$.

Conversely, suppose $a_M$ is not locally nilpotent, so there exists $x \in M$ such that $a^nx = 0$ (I'm guessing this has to be a "$\neq$" and therefore the rest of the proof isn't valid anymore) for all $n\geq 0$. Let $S=\{1,a,a^2,\dots\}$, and using proposition 2.1 let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime not intersecting $S$. Then $(Ax)_{\mathfrak{p}} \neq 0$, so $M_\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$ and $a \notin \mathfrak{p}$, as desired.

Am I right that it has to be a "$\neq$"? If not, can someone fix the proof?

Comment: Why do you think that there has to be an $\neq$?

Comment: Because the negation of $(\forall x \in M)(\exists n \in \mathbb{N})(a^nx=0)$ is $(\exists x \in M)(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(a^nx \neq 0)$.

Comment: The plural of *lemma* is *lemmas* (or *lemmata*, if you want to sound fancy), with no apostrophe involved.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110809/279515

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about $a^nx \neq0$. But then the proof is correct.

You might want to note additionally that $(Ax)_{\mathfrak{p}} \neq 0$ since $x/1\neq0$. And, $a \notin \mathfrak{p}$ since $a \in S$.

Comment: just to complete: AND $M_\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$ since $(Ax)_{\mathfrak{p}} \neq 0$

Comment: $x/1 \neq 0$ since $\mathfrak{p}$ has to be $A-S$, right? Since $A-S$ is an ideal.

Comment: $x/1 \neq 0$ since $p$ has to be $A-S$ and $a^nx \neq0$ for all $n$

Comment: @user1 Your argument shows that if $r \in A$ and $r' \in A - S$, then $rr' \in A - S$, so $A - S$ is closed under multiplication by elements of $A$. But, $A - S$ need not be an additive subgroup. For instance, we could have $-a \in A - S$, so $A - S$ would not be closed under taking additive inverses, and hence it would not be an ideal.

Comment: @MichielVanCouwenberghe I'm quite sure that $A - S$ is not an ideal in general, see my above comment. To show that $(Ax)_\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$, one would have to go through one of the ways given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110809/279515). I particularly like the [OP's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/110843/279515) there.